# django app listening on localhost:8000 vs 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Django app running on Google Kubernetes Engine.If I run the enter the pod , and run netstat -l command. It shows that the service is listening on localhost:8000
[image]

I ran the same service on Elastic Kubernetes service on AWS. There the service didn't respond to the outside requests when the container was listening on localhost:8000.
I had to run `python manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000`, so that container listens on all the network interfaces.
On AWS , the output of netstat -l looks like this
[image]

I want to understand, that

1. Why the same app was running on the google Kubernetes engine, but not on EKS, and I had to specifically define to listen on 0.0.0.0:8000.
2. Why the google Kubernetes engine listens to outside traffic , when the netstat -l shows that it is listening on localhost:8000

The docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7.4

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt

# Set work directory.
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Copy project code.
COPY . /code/

# RUN python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate

# CMD export ENV_Setting=development && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver
```

We start the app in the deployment file:

```
command: ["bash", "-c", "export ENV_Setting=devs && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runscript custom_permissions_script && python manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: Is it the same K8S version in both clusters?

Comment: Can you provide your image's Dockerfile, or other details for a [mcve]?  Normally commands like `netstat` should print out plain text, not images, but just its output isn't really enough to diagnose anything.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere , yes the version for both of them is 1.18

Comment: @DavidMaze, I have added both the docker file and the command which we use in the deployment.yaml

Comment: It seems like you added two images to the question.  I can't `docker build` a PNG file if I need to test it out, and it's hard to find it later if needed.  Please replace all of the images here with the actual text of the source files and the actual text of the error messages.

Comment: @DavidMaze, please check , i have updated the script.

Comment: When traffic reaches a Kubernetes node it will handle the same way regardless of load balancers. They were not aware which nodes in the cluster are running pods for its service. You need to specify that traffic must go to a Pod on the same node. You need to set [externalTrafficPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview) to local in your service manifest.